# Popular array em servidor online

Tags: php, android, mysql

Sou iniciante em programação e estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo android que utiliza PHP e faz requisições com o Mysql. Inicialmente testei todas as funcionalidades no servidor local para, então, migrá-lo para um servidor online, no caso, Hostinger.

Um dos meus arquivos em PHP retorna o valor de um array corretamente no servidor local, porém, ao utilizar o mesmo arquivo em PHP no servidor online com o mesmo banco, o array só responde como TRUE quando executo `echo`.

Testei fazendo o echo de cada linha e está funcionando perfeitamente, só não conseguindo associar os valores às keys.

```
$resultado = array();
$ordenado = mysqli_query($connect, $ordenarExercicio);  

while ($pacientes = $ordenado->fetch_assoc()){  
    echo $pacientes['grupo'];              //imprime OK
    echo $pacientes['nome_exercicio'];     //imprime OK
    echo $pacientes['utilizar_exercicio']; //imprime OK

    $resultado[] = array("grupo" => $pacientes['grupo'],    
                         "nome" => $pacientes['nome_exercicio'],
                         "habilitar" => $pacientes['utilizar_exercicio']
                        ); 

}

echo json_encode($resultado);  //imprime TRUE
```

Comment: É a versão paga. Tenho acesso ao banco pelo phpmyadmin. Nesse mesmo arquivo existem 2 outras queries que funcionam perfeitamente. Os dados estão sendo passados de forma correta, somente o array que está retornando errado.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, eu não entendo bem de ARRAYs em PHP, mas pelo que entendo por base a variavel $resultado não precisa ter *colchetes* antes de inserir o valor, já que o mesmo já vai torná-la uma ARRAY.

```
$resultado = array("grupo" => $pacientes['grupo'],    
                     "nome" => $pacientes['nome_exercicio'],
                     "habilitar" => $pacientes['utilizar_exercicio']
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar a função print_r ($resultados) para ver o resultado do array que está sendo enviado.

E tente tirar tirar os [] da variável $resultado[].